# Find whether the JS is completed executing

Tags: webdriver-io

I am new to webdriverio. In our website, I'm interested to find the whether a JS is completed executing.

For ex: there is file.js which is loaded. This file.js fires an api call. The API call returns with a response. The file.js consume this response and modifies the DOM.

I want to check programmatically if this whole process of JS firing an API, consuming the response and modifying the DOM is completed using WebDriver IO.

Kindly help.

Comment: Can you not just check the DOM for the expected change? Using the usual waitFor methods. Or do you want to also test that the API request is fired? You can probably use something like: https://webdriver.io/docs/wdio-intercept-service/

Comment: Thank you. Let me check this. As I new to this, I am not able to effectively use this.